# Interface for AppCompatActivity where I'm using WilliamChart

Tags: java, android, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, appcompatactivity

I want to use the  WilliamChart for my project but the problem is the cardcontroller should be extended in the class ([Documentation](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart)).

```
public class BarCardOne extends CardController {
```

Since My app uses use AppCompatActivity,

> public class Customer_Screen extends AppCompatActivity
>           implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

It should be extended.  I can't extend both classes because Java Not supports Multiple inheritances. What is the alternative way for it?

Comment: Please have a look at the demo. You don't have to subclass that class.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Where is it mentioned in the Doc? I couldn't find demo! ever though I added the dependency I think I need to extend the class